# JSF csv download

Tags: jsf, csv, backing-beans

Using JSF1.2, I have a group of checkboxes on a page that the user will check to specify what data they want returned in a csv file.  On clicking the submit button, I want to grab the checkbox values and use those to query a database and only return those values in the csv file.  What would the best option be?

Use a commandExButton to call the backing bean and set the values and generate the csv, but then how do I get the response back to the browser?

Use an outputLink to call another servlet that will generate the response, but how do I get the checkbox params to the servlet?

If I use a commandLink to call a servlet, it would use a doPost, but how do I do a navigation rule to not go to a different page?

Many thanks

Comment: See this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968593/jsf-csv-download-in-bean My output throws a nullPointer.

Comment: Then it's `null`. Make sure that it's not `null`.

Comment: I went through the debugger and found that the response is null after I get it from the FacesContext.  Why would that be null at that point?  I tried to just setContentType("text/csv") and then println the getContentType() and nothing is printed.  I thought the response would always exist if taken from the context.  @BalusC