# JSF CSV download in bean

Tags: java, jsf, csv, download

I am trying to do a csv download in the same fashion as here:
[How to provide a file download from a JSF backing bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391838/how-to-stream-a-file-download-in-a-jsf-backing-bean)

My response keeps throwing a `nullPointerException` at the `output.write()` line.  The bean is of the request scope.  Any thoughts as to the null pointer?

```
    try
    {
        //submitForm();
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) fc.getExternalContext().getResponse();

        response.reset();
        response.setContentType("text/csv"); 
        //response.setContentLength(contentLength); 
            response.setHeader ( "Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Reporting-" + 
                    new Date().getTime() + ".csv\"" );

        OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
        String s = "\"Project #\",\"Project Name\",\"Product Feature(s)\",";
        s+="\"Project Status\",";
        s+="\"Install Type\",";
        s+="\"Beta Test\",\"Beta Test New/Updated\",";
        s+="\"Production\",\"Production New/Updated\",";
        s+="\n";
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream( s.getBytes("UTF-8") );
        int nextChar;

         while ((nextChar = is.read()) != -1) 
         {
            output.write(nextChar);
         }
         output.close();

    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This is not a JSF direct problem. You need to [convert String into a Stream](http://stackoverflow.com/q/247161/1065197). Also, don't forget to close the output.

Comment: Modified to InputStream and sent to OutputStream and it is still throwing a nullPointer at output.write.  Thoughts?

Comment: Your `output` variable has a `null` value, what is very strange.

Comment: Are you using portlets or so?

Answer (score 0):

3 things jump out here

1. Failing to call `responseComplete()` on `FacesContext` pretty much means JSF will continue to process the request and you don't get to affect the outcome.
2. The `reset()` call is unnecessary.
3. The outputstream should be of type `ServletOutputStream`

   Try the following snippet instead

   ```
   try
   {
   //submitForm();
   FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
   HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) fc.getExternalContext().getResponse();


   response.setContentType("text/csv"); 
   fc.responseComplete();
   //response.setContentLength(contentLength); 
       response.setHeader ( "Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Reporting-" + 
               new Date().getTime() + ".csv\"" );

   ServletOutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
   String s = "\"Project #\",\"Project Name\",\"Product Feature(s)\",";
   s+="\"Project Status\",";
   s+="\"Install Type\",";
   s+="\"Beta Test\",\"Beta Test New/Updated\",";
   s+="\"Production\",\"Production New/Updated\",";
   s+="\n";
   InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream( s.getBytes("UTF-8") );
   int nextChar;

    while ((nextChar = is.read()) != -1) 
    {
       output.write(nextChar);
    }
       output.flush();

    output.close();

   }
   catch ( IOException e )
   {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

Additionally, you can just call `sos.println(s)` without the need for all that work you're doing there

Comment: This still comes up with an error after the changes.  com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase execute #{DownloadBean.doDownload}: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                 javax.faces.FacesException: #{DownloadBean.doDownload}: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: If I try to do a println on the response.getContentType() right after I set it, it returns nothing.  So it is actually my response that is null because the getContentType() returns nothing.  How can the response be null?

Comment: @user1523885, if `response==null`, then `response.getContentType()` will throw an NPE. Try moving `fc.responseComplete();` up by a line.

Comment: No change.  A response.getContentType() prints nothing and still throws the same error. @kolossus

Comment: @user1523885, give some more context to the code, is this within a managed bean? Is this in response to a commandButton `action` etc.

Comment: Yes, this is response to hx:commandExButton action="#{DownloadBean.doDownload}"